# Average multiple values in same key based on 2nd category in python

Tags: python, list, tuples, average

I have a list which looks something like this

```
[('A1', 'A', 342.5), ('A2', 'A', 509.70), ('A2', 'B', 119.34), 
('A1', 'B', 618.42), ('A1', 'A', 173.54), ('A1', 'B', 235.21)]
```

I'm looking to find the average of the third elements for each type of second element for each first column values. The output would look something like this

```
A1 (A 258.02) (B 426.815)
A2 (A 509.70) (B 119.34)
```

I've been able to do something like this for a list of tuples with two elements but am struggling with three.

If this question has already been answered then please point me there as I couldn't find it myself

Comment: Could you post your code; what you have tried?

Comment: Pandas might make your life easier depending on your use case here. `pd.DataFrame(l).groupby((0, 1)).mean()`

Comment: You could have a look at my solution if you are interested in adding values later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
data = [('A1', 'A', 342.5), ('A2', 'A', 509.70), ('A2', 'B', 119.34),
        ('A1', 'B', 618.42), ('A1', 'A', 173.54), ('A1', 'B', 235.21)]

import itertools as it
for g1 in it.groupby(sorted(data), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    print(g1[0], end=' ')
    for g2 in it.groupby(g1[1], key=lambda x: x[1]):
        nums = [i[2] for i in g2[1]]
        print('(%s %.2f)' % (g2[0], sum(nums) / len(nums)), end=' ')
    print()
```

#### Results:

```
A1 (A 258.02) (B 426.81) 
A2 (A 509.70) (B 119.34)
```

Comment: If one wanted this could also be shortened into a single `groupby`.

Comment: @miradulo, the funky print at the beginning of the line made a single groupby, well funky.

Comment: @StephenRauch Thank you, this is working. I've now applied it to a much larger list of data. Where would I put in the formatting to make the averages to two decimal points?

Comment: @user9784424, I updated the answer with 2 decimal points.

Comment: @StephenRauch thanks yeah been coding for a bit but first time using SO :). 1 final question is there anyway to order the output by the first element i.e. A1, A2, A3 etc. For the larger data set i've got up to A30

Comment: It should already be ordered.  That will be the result of the `sorted()`.

Comment: @StephenRauch It's ordered it A1, A10, A11, .. A2, A20 rather than A1, A2 etc.

Comment: To change the ordering of `sorted`, use the `key`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted

Answer (score 1):

Using nested defaultdict with float

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [('A1', 'A', 342.5), ('A2', 'A', 509.70), ('A2', 'B', 119.34),
     ('A1', 'B', 618.42), ('A1', 'A', 173.54), ('A1', 'B', 235.21)]

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(float)))

for a,b,c in l:
    d[a][b]['sum'] += c
    d[a][b]['count'] += 1
    d[a][b]['average'] += (c - d[a][b]['average'])/d[a][b]['count']
```

We use the fact that the average can be calculates as (see: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/957376/)

[image]

Returns the following structure:

```
{
  "A1": {
    "A": {
      "sum": 516.04,
      "count": 2.0,
      "average": 258.02
    },
    "B": {
      "sum": 853.63,
      "count": 2.0,
      "average": 426.815
    }
  },
  "A2": {
    "A": {
      "sum": 509.7,
      "count": 1.0,
      "average": 509.7
    },
    "B": {
      "sum": 119.34,
      "count": 1.0,
      "average": 119.34
    }
  }
}
```

---

With this you can easily add more data, e.g. running this again:

```
l = [('A1', 'A', 100)]

for a,b,c in l:
    d[a][b]['sum'] += c
    d[a][b]['count'] += 1
    d[a][b]['average'] += (c - d[a][b]['average'])/d[a][b]['count']
```

---

```
for k,v in d.items():
    print(k)
    print('-------------')
    for k2, v2 in v.items():    
        print(k2)  
        for k3, v3 in v2.items(): 
            print('{}: {}'.format(k3,v3))
        print()
```

Returns:

```
A1
-------------
A
sum: 616.04
count: 3.0
average: 205.34666666666666

B
sum: 853.63
count: 2.0
average: 426.815

A2
-------------
A
sum: 509.7
count: 1.0
average: 509.7

B
sum: 119.34
count: 1.0
average: 119.34
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy to construct a suitable data structure to hold the data:

```
d = [('A1', 'A', 342.5), ('A2', 'A', 509.70), ('A2', 'B', 119.34),
     ('A1', 'B', 618.42), ('A1', 'A', 173.54), ('A1', 'B', 235.21)]

In []:
r = {}
for a, b, c in d:
    r.setdefault(a, {}).setdefault(b, []).append(c)
r

Out[]:
{'A1': {'A': [342.5, 173.54], 'B': [618.42, 235.21]}, 'A2': {'A': [509.7], 'B': [119.34]}}
```

Then you can just iterate through this doing the sums:

```
In []:
{k1: {k2: sum(v2)/len(v2) for k2, v2 in v1.items()} for k1, v1 in r.items()}

Out[]:
{'A1': {'A': 258.02, 'B': 426.815}, 'A2': {'A': 509.7, 'B': 119.34}}
```

Comment: If you are going to downvote, please provide feedback.

Comment: I did not downvote, but this would have been my first option had I answered the question. +1

Answer (score 0):

Generate a dictionary of all the values first, and then average them.

So, if we name your list `l`, you can do:

```
d = {}
for a, b, c in l:
    d.setdefault(a, {}).setdefault(b, []).append(c)

d = {p: {r: sum(s) / len(s) for r, s in q.items()} for p, q in d.items()}
```

which gives `d` as:

```
{
    'A1': {
        'A': 258.02,
        'B': 426.815
    },
    'A2': {
        'A': 509.7,
        'B': 119.34
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this really easy in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

l = [('A1', 'A', 342.5), ('A2', 'A', 509.70), ('A2', 'B', 119.34),
     ('A1', 'B', 618.42), ('A1', 'A', 173.54), ('A1', 'B', 235.21)]

df = pd.DataFrame(l)
print(df.groupby([0, 1]).mean())
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Any feedback for downvote is appreciated.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I'm guessing it is because using Pandas is overkill for this

Comment: Fair, can't disagree for the contrived example. Thanks.

Comment: I downvoted your answer because pandas, while brilliant and wondrous, was not explicitly asked for here. And the solution for this problem is not sufficiently complicated to justify its installation and use (it _is_ in some other cases though).

Comment: I agree with Coldspeed. Your answer is fine, just tough to say if Pandas is warranted or not without a lot more context for what they are doing (which is why I'll advertise it in a comment instead usually).

Comment: Keyword for me was "something like". I appreciate the feedback.